# Can't get overflow-y: scroll to work

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a vertical timeline but I can't seem to get the `overflow-y: scroll` to work. Here is a link to the website:

http://fosterinnovationculture.com/infographic/index.html

The parent div has an `overflow: hidden` but the child div has overflow-y. It works properly if I remove the parent div but I need it inside of the div so that list.js plugin works properly.

Answer (score 2):

I see your code have

> html, body {
>       overflow: hidden;
>   }

// it mean only full screen and all overflow is hidden.

So in .scroll you need set max-height. I suggest a solution

> .scroll {
>       max-height: 90vh;
>   }

Comment: Awesome! This fixed it. How is max-heigh different from height?

Comment: max-height is maximum it can do, height only fixed  one value and not change if container grow

Answer (score 0):

You fixed the height of `body` to 100vh and set it's overflow property's value to `hidden`;
So not matter whatever the height of `body`'s child is, it will not scroll;

If you change body's overflow property to `auto`, scroll will work;

At the same time you may change the `position` of `top_nav` to `fixed`, in order to keep the search bar at the top all time time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are repeating the same question. Here is [you asking about](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37707522/756329) the same problem (though I will admit the question is different because it has changed). Here is [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37708118/756329) to that question.

---

Before giving an answer, I will say that the most important thing I tell myself when coding CSS is: if I start having to hack then I am making it too complicated.

With that said, start by removing every instance of `overflow: hidden;` in your code.

Then get this in there:

```
.top-nav {
    height: 70px; /* you already specify this on your site */
}
.scroll {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

---

In cases like this, you should try to realize that your question regards a design that is common and someone else must have asked your question before. If you cannot find an answer to such a question, it may be good to rethink your search keywords.

Here is [a Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9677894/756329) that answers your underlying "how-to" design question.